# Find source from percentage number

Tags: percentages

Yeah, I might look stupid with this question but Math classes are so long ago for me :).

I need to find the exact number that makes `18.20`, `82%` off.

So to clarify:

```
(?) * 0.82 = 18.2
```

How do i find that number? Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact wording of your exercise ? Im not sure what the meaning of "82% off" in this context is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(?) $*\: 0.82 = 18.2$

You divide by $0.82$.

Let $x$ be the number you are looking for.

$x \cdot 0.82 = 18.2$

$\frac{x \cdot 0.82}{0.82} = \frac{18.2}{0.82}$

$\require{cancel}\frac{x \cdot \cancel{0.82}}{\cancel{0.82}} = \frac{18.2}{0.82}$

$$x = \frac{18.2}{0.82} = \frac{910}{41} = 22.1951219512195122$$

Comment: So simple. Geezz, I knew it! Thanks man!

Comment: @Nique No problem

Answer (score 0):

If 18.20 is 82% off, then 18.20 is 100-82% = 18% of 'some number'.

So we want to know what 100% of this 'some number' is.

So $\frac{100}{18} * 18.2 = 101.11$

Answer (score 0):

$18.20$ is $82$% off of what number $x$?

What number $x$ multiplied by $.82$ yields $18.20$?

Well, $.82 \cdot x=18.20\implies x=18.2/.82 \approx 22.2$

In other words: divide by $.82$

Comment: So simpe. :) I was afraid for that haha Thanks

Comment: no worries! It'll be easy to pick everything back up in a lil bit